# How to delete iOS runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've downloaded and installed iOS 8.4 Simulator from here Xcode > Preferences > Components. And now i don't need it anymore. How can i delete this runtime?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can find them in:

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

Also restart Xcode when removing.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and there are no folders like Profiles or Runtimes by this path: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Comment: Yes, I made it. It was my mistake, I was looking for those folders under my user's directory...Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you can not find the folder that @Majster mentioned, it's likely because you are looking at `Library/` in your **user folder**.

**1)** Open a terminal `cmd+space` and type `terminal`.

**2)** Copy-Paste this command into terminal: `open /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

This will open the correct folder where your simulators are.

**3)** Delete the simulators you don't want

**4)** Restart xcode.

Comment: This is no longer the case. It looks like the location has moved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when the change was made, if this is Xcode-beta specific, or otherwise; however, with my copy of code, the simulator runtimes were stored in `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`.

If you were unable to find yours elsewhere, check this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode and go to `Xcode > Settings... (⌘ + ,) > Platforms`. You may select the existing simulator (runtime) from the list and press the backspace or `-` button to delete it